# What triggers the isFinal property of a pan event in Hammerjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

I am using HammerJS to handle a simple drag and drop scenario. I want the element to bounce back when it is within a certain region of my bounding box or zoom off the screen if it is outside of that. I am using the isFinal property to get determine when to call the callback function, which handles the bouncing back. The issue is, it could be that I am not clear on how the 'pan' event works, that unless the element is still moving when the mouse is released, it gets stuck and the isFinal property stays false.

So what I need to figure out is how to trigger the isFinal property at anytime when the element is released.

The code is below for some context.

```
    var registerNodeDraggable = function(oArgs) {
        if (!oArgs.id || !oArgs.el) { return; }

        var x = parseInt(oArgs.el.style.left,10) || 0;
        //var y = parseInt(oArgs.el.style.top,10) || 0;

        window[oArgs.id + 'Hammer'] = {
            hammer: new window.Hammer(oArgs.el),
            x: x,
            //y: y
    };

        var obj = window[oArgs.id + 'Hammer'];

        if (obj.hammer) {
            obj.hammer.on('panleft panright', function(e) {
                console.log(e);
                console.log(e.deltaTime);
                console.log(e.type);
                oArgs.el.style.left = obj.x + e.deltaX + 'px';
                // oArgs.el.style.top = obj.y + e.deltaY + 'px';
                if (e.isFinal && oArgs.callback) {
                    console.log('Is Final');
                    obj.x += e.deltaX;
                    //obj.y += e.deltaY;

                    oArgs.callback.call(this, e, obj);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    registerNodeDraggable({
        el: this.$ticker[0],
        id: 'swipe',
        callback: function(e, obj) {

            console.log('I am being called');

            //self.$ticker.velocity({opacity: 0});
            var $container = $('.tickerContainer');
            var offset = $container.offset();
            var tickerOffset = self.$ticker.position();
            var offsetRight = $container.width()  - self.$ticker.width() -  tickerOffset.left;
            var offsetBottom = $container.height() - self.$ticker.height() - tickerOffset.top;

            console.log(offsetRight + ' :Right');
            console.log(tickerOffset.left + ' :Left');


            if( offsetRight < -30 ){
                console.log('Bull');
                self.$ticker.velocity({translateX: 1000, opacity: 0},{duration: 250, complete: function(){
                    self.$ticker.velocity({ left:0, top: 0,  translateX: 0 }, {complete: function() {
                        obj.x = 0;
                        //obj.y = 0;
                         self.pick(self._nextTicker.ticker, 'Bull'); console.log('Bull');
                    } });
                } });

            } else if(tickerOffset.left < -30){
                console.log('Bear');
                self.$ticker.velocity({translateX: -1000, opacity: 0},{duration: 250, complete: function(){
                    self.$ticker.velocity({ left:0, top: 0,  translateX: 0 }, {complete: function() {
                        obj.x = 0;
                        //obj.y = 0;
                        self.pick(self._nextTicker.ticker, 'Bear'); console.log('Bear');
                    } });
                } });
            } else {
                self.$ticker.velocity({
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0 },
                    {duration: 250,
                    complete: function(){
                    obj.x = 0;
                    //obj.y = 0;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Any insight on this?

Comment: I haven't gotten any. I'm still in the same spot I was before.

Comment: Roger that. I'll keep on looking. I let you know if I gather any info on this

Answer (score 4):

afaik `isFinal` is `true`, when the mouse is released. But I think, it's not the way to handle it. Found this:

"The isFirst and isFinal are kind of internal properties, used by Hammer, but exposed anyway (doesn't hurt)" [1](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/574)

Instead of unsing `e.isFinal`, do this:

```
obj.hammer.on('panend',function(e){/*...*/});
```

But I think, you have to do it another way.
So, as I understood, you want manually set the `isFinal` property to `true`, so that your "pandleft/right" handler will fire the callback.

Try this:

after initializing the Hammer Object, add some custom Data:

```
window[oArgs.id + 'Hammer'] = {
        hammer: new window.Hammer(oArgs.el),
        x: x,
        //y: y
};
window[oArgs.id + 'Hammer'].hammer.customData = {isFinal: false};
```

change

```
if (e.isFinal && oArgs.callback) {
```

to

```
if (obj.hammer.customData.isFinal && oArgs.callback) {
```

When you think, it's time to set `isFinal`  `true` (based on your own rules and beliefs):

```
window[oArgs.id + 'Hammer'].hammer.customData.isFinal = true;
```

maybe, you want to set the property to `false` again in you callback.

Comment: Thanks! `isFinal` did not work, I wonder why it's in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Note in IOS 13 the `panend` and `isFinal` [may not be triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089104/ios-13-not-raising-panend-events-when-changing-panning-direction/58089133#58089133) if you're not listening for `pancancel` also.

At time of writing iOS 13 has just been released - so be sure to test on 12 and 13 for different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i.e. isFinal was not reliably showing up in an event at the end of the pan. Simply adding 'panend' to the events I was listening for in my handler solved the problem. Now it looks like this and works 100% of the time:

```
this.mc.on('panleft panright panend', event => {
```