# IOS 13 not raising panend events when changing panning direction

Tags: hammer.js, ios13

I have a custom image slider using Hammer.js events.

I use the following to create my 'hammer' object:

```
    const hammerPan = new Hammer(domElement, 
    {
        // lock vertical scrolling when panning left to right
        touchAction: 'pan-y',

        recognizers: [
            // we don't care about vertical, but we want always to get panstart and panend
            // events so we use ALL to prevent unncesessary filtering from hammerjs
            [Hammer.Pan, { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 10 }]
        ]
    });
```

The slider (like most sliders) moves left to right, but to avoid blocking vertical scroll on mobile devices I use `touchAction: 'pan-y'` so I can still scroll.

In IOS 12 everything worked just fine - **even if I panned left and then moved my finger up before releasing. This would trigger some vertical pan events but would still end in panend**.

With IOS 13 (and I have two phones to compare) it would not give me a final `panend` event so my slides would get 'stuck' halfway.

Comment: Facing same issue, even after trying the given solution? 
Were you able to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes but I only had a pretty simple case where my solution was enough

Answer (score 1):

Excuse RxJS syntax if this is unfamiliar to you, but all I needed to do was explicitly add the `pancancel` event.

```
const panUnfilteredRaw$ = fromEvent<HammerInput>(hammerPan as unknown as JQueryStyleEventEmitter, 
                          'panstart panmove panend pancancel').pipe(share());
```

I previously did not have this because either I copied it from somewhere, or I just never thought I needed it.

Not sure if IOS13 is being more or less picky (!) but it's certainly got different behavior if you change direction of panning - so  arguably it is a bug.

---

I also switched from detecting `panend` to `event.isFinal`.